# warden other than .test domain name

Tags: local

I'm using this great tool called [warden](https://github.com/davidalger/warden) for local development and I'm currently in need of setting up Magento on a different domain tld - other than ".test" (it needs to be example.local, the reason being that it needs to be connected to a remote database.)

How can I set this up using warden?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lukasz Bajserowicz I was able to resolve this issue. This is also described at https://docs.warden.dev/services.html

The new domain name needs to be configured in the .env file and added to dnsmasq configuration (at https://dnsmasq.warden.test).